# Text index of a field containing path in Oracle

Tags: oracle, indexing, full-text-indexing

I have an Oracle table of which one of the columns contains text path to some element in a tree, for example "Node1/Node2/Node4/Leaf23". I would like to speed up the queries utilizing this column in its filters, especially using LIKE and % wildcard character (e.g. LIKE 'Node1/Node%'). Is there any mechanism in Oracle which could help me in this? Some sort of data type which will allow to treat these paths like something different than string?

When it comes to indexing I was thinking about Oracle Text, but I don't know if it will be performing well with this specific kind of short text strings - I believe Oracle Text was meant for some bigger and more complex texts.

Comment: `LIKE 'Node1/Node%'` **will** an index on that column. No special magic required. but: `LIKE '%Node1/Node%'` will never use an index in Oracle

Comment: OK, I did not precise myself sufficiently. I know, that existing text index will make use of all the characters up until the first occurence of wildcard character. I am more curious about ways to handle cases like '%something%'.